# How to write a proper unit test for file transformation

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I'm not very familiar with unit testing, I just start with learning how to do it. Maybe I haven't really understood the principles of unit testing and TDD and that's the reason why I'm feeling stuck.

The code to test looks like this:

```
class DevelopingMyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.firstAttribute = None

    def openGivenFile(self, filename):
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        return f

    def transformInput(self, filename):
        res = self.openGivenFile(filename)
        for line in res.readlines():
            newLine = line.replace('a', 'z')
            print(newLine)

# start
myClass = DevelopingMyClass()
myClass.transformInput('testfile.txt')
```

Of course, this program does not make any sense. I was just trying to figure out:

- is this testable? and if yes, what exactly makes it testable?
- do I have to write two test cases, one for the opening method and one for the transformation?
- do I have to mock the opening, so that I am independent of the existence of a testfile?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried several examples, to mock out the open function, but none of them worked. I tried to change them accordingly but failed...

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons why unit tests help during development is that they reveal if your interfaces are designed correctly. Think about unit test as about a program of someone else who wants to use the functionality designed by you.

In your case, I can see the problem in using the `print` inside the `transformInput` method. Also the `DevelopingMyClass` is a misleading identifier. I do not want to be picky. It simply makes your thinking less clear.

Before you dive into unit testing, you should choose a decent example. There can be no nice unit test for a nonsense.

Fistly, if you want to read the file, modify the content, and write the file back, then you should start with a plain function. The class will not help you here. You may be used to from Java where you always create some object first. But it actually is not natural. Objects are good if you need to keep some instance variables inside (some status).

If the functionality is to be more general, it should not use side effects like the `print`.

Say, you have never heard about TDD and you write the code like this:

```
#!python3

def copy_and_filter(fname_from, fname_to):
    with open(fname_from) as fin, open(fname_to, 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            fout.write(line.replace('a', 'z'))


copy_and_filter('from.txt', 'to.txt')
```

(This is actually your solution.) You will find TDD more reasonable for more complex code. Anyway. You should start thinking like:

- I need a function that takes takes one source filename and one target filename. Both files are text files.
- It copies the content of the source file changes the content and writes it to the destination.

So you write:

```
#!python3

def copy_and_filter(fname_from, fname_to):
    pass


copy_and_filter('from.txt', 'to.txt')
```

This way you define how it should be called. Now is the time to write unit tests. You want to test special cases:

- empty file
- several cases of files with a known content

Later, you may observe that there is a bug when the source file does not exist (the implementation should reflect that), so you add some test and then fix the implementation.

Other problems that may be expected:
- the source file is not a source file (say it is a directory)
- the target cannot be open for writing
- the target file is already exists and you do not want to overwrite it

When testing with more files, you will discover that it is difficult to simulate the files, and you may decide to change the internals so that the core functionality works with file-like objects.